# How to read a pin in linux4arm via the device tree?

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, gpio, device-tree

Reading GPIOs via memory maps is well documented. But what with reading them via device tree table?
Let's take the SAMA5D3x eval board as example. The device tree under sys looks like:

```
root@sama5d3xek:/sys# find . -name gpio
./devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/ahb:apb:pinctrl@fffff200/fffffa00.gpio/gpio
./devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/ahb:apb:pinctrl@fffff200/fffff600.gpio/gpio
./devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/ahb:apb:pinctrl@fffff200/fffff800.gpio/gpio
./devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/ahb:apb:pinctrl@fffff200/fffff200.gpio/gpio
./devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/ahb:apb:pinctrl@fffff200/fffff400.gpio/gpio
./class/gpio
./kernel/debug/gpio
```

For example:

1. set PD13 as input + read it
2. set PA6 as output + write to it

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt

Comment: very useful - in that case "echo 109 > export" activates PD13. How it looks like in C? When I get it right at the "drivers-on-gpio.txt" it is said that I rather should use the DT than memory maps to access the hardware. What's the actual opinion?

Comment: You seem confused.  The Device Tree is solely for configuration.  You cannot use it for I/O.  The copy of the DT in **sysfs** is for informational use, and not for I/O.  The gpio interface provided by **sysfs** (which is distinct from the copy of the DT) is preferred over direct access to the pin & gpio registers through **mmap()**, because then there is little risk of interference or conflicts with other pins used by other device drivers.  IOW the **sysfs** gpio interface adheres to the same pin & gpio resource control as other drivers.

Comment: when I got it right need to request the PIN via gpio_request(PD13); set it as input via gpio_direction_input(PD13); and read it via gpio_get_value(PD13)